# How can I access the content of something created with <ui:define> programmatically?

Tags: jsf, facelets

Where in the contexts can I find the information for something built with a `<ui:define>`? I want to access a page title that has been defined with `<ui:define name="title">Some title</ui:define>` in my bean.

To illustrate my question, I can access a variable defined with

```
<ui:param name="myVariable" value="This is my variable!"/>
```

by looking at the variable mapper in the EL context, like this

```
VariableMapper variableMapper = elContext.getVariableMapper();
String myVariable = variableMapper.resolveVariable("myVariable").getValue(elContext).toString();
```

This works for `<ui:param>`, but how is it done for `<ui:define>`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with it? It basically represents a partial JSF component tree and not necessarily a plain vanilla String like ui:param.

Comment: @BalusC: I simply want to check, if something called `title` had been defined and if not, set a generic page title.. and I am curious, how this can be done programmatically. I was searching for the component tree with the key `title` in the contexts, but could not find it.

Comment: OK, you basically want to check if `<ui:define name="title">` for an `<ui:insert name="title">` has been defined in the template client, regardless of the content? I.e. you're only interested in having a boolean `true` or `false` based on that which you can then use elsewhere in the template? If so, is this then acceptable as dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070704/possible-to-test-if-uiinsert-has-content/

Comment: @BalusC: The page title should have this form: `AppName - PageTitle`. Some pages do not define a `PageTitle`, they get `AppName` as a generic title. Some do and for these pages the defined `PageTitle` shall be concatenated with the `AppName` and `dash` prefix.

As I was working on this, I tried to retrieve the content of the `ui:define` in a bean, to see how and where this information is stored in a context and could not find it. I spent hours trying to solve this and I could not find any relevant information about this on the net. Any hints in the right direction are also very welcome.

Comment: @BalusC: The link you have provided is definitely an acceptable solution for this problem, but I am interested in learning how to access the ui:define block via code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible via standard API. Xtreme Biker has posted a brilliant trick whereby a "default" `<ui:param>` value is specified inside the `<ui:insert>` which would be overriden (and thus absent) when a `<ui:define>` is actually specified as answer on [Test if ui:insert has been defined in the template client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070704/possible-to-test-if-uiinsert-has-content/)

A (hacky) alternative would be to create a custom taghandler for the job. The `<ui:define>`s are by their name collected in `Map handlers` field of the `CompositionHandler` taghandler class behind `<ui:composition>`. This is (unfortunately) implementation specific, [Mojarra](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.9/com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/ui/CompositionHandler.java#CompositionHandler) and [MyFaces](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/2.2.7/org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/tag/ui/CompositionHandler.java#CompositionHandler) have their own implementations whereby Mojarra has named the field `handlers` and MyFaces `_handlers`.

As the field is just `protected`, cleanest would be to just extend the `CompositionHandler` taghandler class and expose at least the keyset in the `apply()` method as attribute of `FaceletContext`. However, as the `CompositionHandler` class itself is declared `final`, we can't subclass it. Therefore, we can't go around wrapping it as a delegate and use some reflection hackery to grab the field anyway.

Here's a kickoff example based on Mojarra which collects all declared `<ui:define>` handler names in a `Map<String, Boolean>` so that you can nicely use them in EL like so `#{defined.foo ? '...' : '...'}` respectively `#{not defined.foo ? '...' : '...'}`.

```
public class DefineAwareCompositionHandler extends TagHandlerImpl implements TemplateClient {

    private CompositionHandler delegate;
    private Map<String, Boolean> defined;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DefineAwareCompositionHandler(TagConfig config) {
        super(config);
        delegate = new CompositionHandler(config);

        try {
            Field field = delegate.getClass().getDeclaredField("handlers");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Map<String, DefineHandler> handlers = (Map<String, DefineHandler>) field.get(delegate);

            if (handlers != null) {
                defined = new HashMap<>();

                for (String name : handlers.keySet()) {
                    defined.put(name, true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FaceletException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent parent) throws IOException {
        ctx.setAttribute("defined", defined);
        delegate.apply(ctx, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent parent, String name) throws IOException {
        return delegate.apply(ctx, parent, name);
    }

}
```

Register it as follows in your custom `my.taglib.xml`:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>composition</tag-name>
    <handler-class>com.example.DefineAwareCompositionHandler</handler-class>
</tag>
```

You could make use of it as below:

```
<my:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/ui"
>
    <ui:insert name="foo">
        ...
    </ui:insert>

    <div class="#{defined.foo ? 'style1' : 'style2'}">
        ...
    </div>
</my:composition>
```

Again, this is hacky (as it's implementation specific), I'd not recommend using it.

#### See also:

- [Custom Facelet component in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006955/custom-facelet-component-in-jsf)

Comment: I see now why I could not find information about this so easily. Thank you very much for providing so much insight.