# Test if a jsf template facelet content is defined by a template client using ui:define

Tags: jsf

I'm building a template using jsf  tags that has an optional sidebar. To render the html for the sidebar, I need to check if it's content is actually defined. More specifically, I'm trying to do this: (element classes are from bootstrap)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="#{ check_if_has_sidebar ? 'col-md-9' : 'col-md-12' }">
        page content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" jsf:rendered="#{check_if_has_sidebar}">
        <ui:insert name="sidebar-content" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I check if the page using this template defines content for "sidebar-content" using ui:define?

The following solution (suggested in a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070704/possible-to-test-if-uiinsert-has-content)) doesn't work because I need to check BEFORE the definition of the param 'noSideBar':

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="#{ noSideBar ? 'col-md-9' : 'col-md-12' }">
        page content
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" jsf:rendered="#{not noSideBar}">
        <ui:insert name="sidebar-content">
            <ui:param name="noSideBar" value="true" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did it really not work during runtime? Or was that just your own untested assumption?

Comment: It not work, I tested. The div for page contents uses the class 'col-md-9' independently if the sidebar is defined or not by the template client. Also, the div with the sidebar content (the one with the jsf:rendered parameter) is always rendered. If I invert the order of the divs, the class applied is correct, but the div for the sidebar is still rendered even though no sidebar is defined. Since I need a right sidebar, I cannot invert the order in my code.

Comment: I know, but technical expectation is that ui:param is executed during view build time not during view render time. So code must just work. Which JSF impl/version are you using? In meanwhile, work around is to use `<c:set var="noSideBar" value="true" scope="request"/>` instead of that `<ui:param>`.

Comment: I'm using Mojarra 2.2.7. It worked with    <c:set />. Thanks!

Comment: Is there really no way of testing if `<ui:defined>` is set without checking `<ui:param>`? The importance is to automatically render decoration in the template only when there is something to render for the `<ui:insert>`.